# java.security.AccessControlException in Applet

Tags: java, exception, applet, appletviewer

Inside my Applet, it needs to download the csv file from other site to run.

When i run applet with appletviewer, it gave me this exception :

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermision www.xxxsitexxx.com:80 connect, resolve
   ....
```

My applet's signed :

```
 jarsigner -verify myfile.jar >> the result :  jar verified.
```

I tried to add :

```
grant {
      permission java.security.AllPermission;
    };
```

into Tomcat's folder :

```
..conf/catalina.policy
```

But it didn't work.

Google suggests me to add security permisson to :

```
... jre/lib/security/java.policy
```

But I couldn't change it :

```
Access to ... jre/lib/security/java.policy was denied.
```

My question is :

1. Does add permission to java.policy solve to problem?
2. If so, how could I change java.policy's content?

PS : I read many questions here relate to my problem in Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find the right way to solve it.

```
EDIT : i got the Applet work by signing all jar files that needed to run with the Applet.
```

Comment: Are you prompted to accept the digitally signed code when the applet is loaded by the browser?  The policy files will not be useful at time of deployment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Yes, the browser asked me whether block the applet from being run or not.. Due to Andih'd advice, the applet is now runnable in appletviewer, but in browser, it doesn't work..